# Error when downloading raster from GeoServer -All factories fail for the operation "Scale"

Tags: geoserver, wms, tomcat

Im trying to download raster image from geoserver using wms and sending request to url like this:

*192.168.4.162:8080/geoserver/fiware/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=fiware:test&styles=&bbox=-87.3539257,38.3719729154,-87.3437449312,38.3783359&width=29818&height=18635&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image/geotiff*
And this is the return value:

Error rendering coverage on the fast path
    javax.media.jai.util.ImagingException: All factories fail for the operation "Scale"
    All factories fail for the operation "Scale"Invalid scanline stride

I tried 1% lesser width and height than those from url, and it worked well but for these values it fails.Dimensions of original image are 32768,20479 so im requesting for image in 10% less resolution from GeoServer but it can't return such Geotiff. This raster was uploaded as a mosaic.

Geoserver log shows this:

```
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Error rendering coverage on the fast path....
Caused by: org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: javax.media.jai.util.ImagingException: All factories fail for the operation "Scale"
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.directRasterRender(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:1083)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:344)
    ... 118 more
Caused by: javax.media.jai.util.ImagingException: All factories fail for the operation "Scale"
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1687)
    at it.geosolutions.jaiext.ConcurrentOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ConcurrentOperationRegistry.java:576)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:819)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at javax.media.jai.operator.ScalePropertyGenerator.getProperty(ScaleDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.geotools.image.ImageWorker.affine(ImageWorker.java:4189)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.affine(GridCoverageRenderer.java:639)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.symbolize(GridCoverageRenderer.java:455)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.renderImage(GridCoverageRenderer.java:974)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.renderImage(GridCoverageRenderer.java:768)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.directRasterRender(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:975)
    ... 119 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    ... 131 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid scanline stride
    at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.getBufferSize(ComponentSampleModel.java:274)
    at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.verify(ComponentSampleModel.java:252)
    at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.<init>(ComponentSampleModel.java:170)
    at java.awt.image.PixelInterleavedSampleModel.<init>(PixelInterleavedSampleModel.java:87)
    at java.awt.image.PixelInterleavedSampleModel.createCompatibleSampleModel(PixelInterleavedSampleModel.java:144)
    at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.setImageLayout(PlanarImage.java:523)
    at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.<init>(PlanarImage.java:396)
    at javax.media.jai.OpImage.<init>(OpImage.java:829)
    at javax.media.jai.GeometricOpImage.<init>(GeometricOpImage.java:263)
    at javax.media.jai.ScaleOpImage.<init>(ScaleOpImage.java:427)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.ScaleNearestOpImage.<init>(ScaleNearestOpImage.java:64)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.ScaleCRIF.create(ScaleCRIF.java:126)
    ... 136 more
```

BTW i am using tomcat as a container for Geoserver.
Has anyone encountered error like this, and can someone help me interpret its meaning?

Comment: Instead of using WMS for raster retrieval, i started using WCS service, and i don't have this problem anymore.